# Entity Framework exception "Ambiguous match found."

Tags: entity-framework

**Is there a way to use property hiding in Entity Framework 5.0?**
  Where a base property is hidden with a new type.
In this example    object Id is replaced with new int Id

```
public abstract class BaseObject : IFBaseObject {
    [NotMapped]
    protected virtual object Id { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

public abstract class BaseObjectInt : BaseObject, IFKeyInt {
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public new virtual int Id { set; get; }

 public class MessageRef : BaseObjectInt{
   public virtual string Category { get; set; }
   public virtual string message { get; set; }
}
```

The Entity Framework model seems to work.
   The Database is created as expected.
   However EF throws a reflection Exception when adding values.
   ** Ambiguous match found**

```
Context.Set<TPoco>().AddOrUpdate(poco);
```

If i remove base Property

```
// protected virtual object Id { get; set; }
```

Then EF works, but I get other non EF issues arise with generics since base type has no Id.

The trace in case of interest.

at System.RuntimeType.GetPropertyImpl(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Type returnType, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
   at System.Type.GetProperty(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass12`3.<CombineSelectors>b__11(TSource x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Aggregate[TSource,TAccumulate](IEnumerable`1 source, TAccumulate seed, Func`3 func)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.IDbSetExtensions.AddOrUpdate[TEntity](DbSet`1 set, IEnumerable`1 identifyingProperties, TEntity[] entities)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.IDbSetExtensions.AddOrUpdate[TEntity](IDbSet`1 set, TEntity[] entities)

Comment: You don't want property hiding in the heart of your application. Normally you'd solve this with generics but I'm not sure if EF is going to like that any better. What is so urgent about being able to have generic access to the Id values?

Comment: Hi Gert, I prefer not using dynamic code to access repositories. Im forced to use "dynamic" repositories or Dynamic lambda. Dynamic lambda is not my favourite approach either as it is quiet cumbersome to construct. I have since removed the base property But would like to use the known "patterns" with intellisence support.   For now im back to generics repositories being dynamically invoked. :-(  Frustratingly the  variant patterns with our pocos work outside of EF nicely.  Its a shame we cant indicate to EF type info so the Reflection isnt necessary.

Comment: btw Gert, your comment may need to be escalated to Answer soon

Comment: FYI, I used fields rather than properties to get around issue. And added ID to base object.