# Entity Framework Exception: Ambiguous match found

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I get the error:

> Ambiguous match found

During this code on the .Add

```
var db = new NexusEntities(); 
db.Reports.Add(mmr);
```

From googling it appears to be an issue if the there are two classes with the same name but in different namespaces. As far as I can tell this is not the case... Is there another reason why this error can happen? Or is there a way to tell which parameter it is finding two of?

Comment: What is the type of `mmr`? And what is the type of `Reports`?

Comment: Reports is a type of `Reports` which is an abstract class. mmr is type `MonthlyMarketingReport` which has a base class of `Reports`

Comment: Hard to see without the code in the entities Report & MonthlyMarketingReport.  Are you doing anything funky with hiding properties etc? [refer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218799/entity-framework-exception-ambiguous-match-found?rq=1)

Comment: Is that the entire error? Is it a compilation or runtime error?

Comment: @CodeCaster Entire error, runtime.

Answer (score 22):

This is a "weakness" in EF.   It happens when the same property  appears in class / subtype hierarchy.

Most likely you have a hidden field.  i.e. a property that has been redefined. 
When EF looks for the a property it too must use the type/base tree to find the property. But if it finds it twice in the tree, it interprets this as a duplicate.  EF doesnt just use the lowest most specific override.

So property hiding is not possible with EF.

Check your classes, a property will occur twice somewhere.

Comment: Is there an easy way to find which property?

Comment: @ kirsten... not that im aware of

Comment: l did find the compiler warnings helped me isolate where my similar problem was

Comment: @kirsteng and anyone else hitting this problem, an easy way to work out the problem property: when the exception is thrown go to the call stack window, right click -> show external code, right click -> show parameter values, then look through the stack for hints. Mine was the 3rd from the top (propertyOrFieldName):   `System.Core.dll!System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.PropertyOrField(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expression = {System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression}, string propertyOrFieldName = "Country_State") Unknown`

Comment: To help find what property was causing the issue, I used Linqpad and just started listing top 100 of each class type.  This will eventually show which class is causing the problem.

Comment: This happened to me when a property was the same but capitalization differed.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is probably a much less likely scenario, but we were running `EF Core 1.0` which had only one version of the `Include()` method... in version 1.1, Microsoft added a second implementation (the string version) and since we were calling this method dynamically we got this error after updating our `EF Core` to 1.1