# The item with identity [x] already exists in the metadata collection. How do I fix that?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, poco

I'm using Entity Framework 6, with POCO and fluent-API and I've noticed an annoying bug.

If I have an entity called `MyEntity` and this entity has a property called `MyProp`, that makes it impossible to create an entity called `MyEntity_MyProp`.

Exception:

```
The item with identity 'MyEntity_MyProp' already exists in the metadata collection.\r\nParameter name: item
```

The error immediately goes away if I rename any of the entities, or rename the properties.

The "bug" is obvious: the key [EntityName]_[PropertyName] must be unique in the metadata collection.

Screenshot:

[image]

I'm migrating a huge Entity Framework model with 390+ classes from EF 4, database first, to EF 6, code first, with fluent-API. It's out of question to rename the entities or the tables.

How do I solve that?

**EDIT**

This SO question doesn't have anything to do with my problem: [The item with identity 'Id' already exists in the metadata collection. Parameter name: item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23213271/the-item-with-identity-id-already-exists-in-the-metadata-collection-parameter)

Comment: I was having this problem with EF 6.1.2. I upgraded to EF 6.1.3 and the problem magically disappeared.

Comment: I'm on 6.2 and the problem is there for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a known bug. It's currently scheduled to be fixed in an arbitrary `future` version, that is, it's not in the road-map yet.

Source: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2084

**EDIT**:

According to @Anthony, this was fixed in v6.1.3

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't fixed in 6.1.3, I still can reproduce it.
An issue exist in github : https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/308

Comment: Can confirm it's not fixed in 6.1.3

Comment: I get the same issue in version 6.4.0

Comment: The same issue in version 6.4.4

Answer (score 18):

This bug happens when you use underscores in the name of your entities. The reason is Entity Framework also uses underscores to create the names of the keys (concatenating the entity and property names).

So, if you have an entity named "Table" with a property "Prop" and a table named "Table_Prop" a clash will occur. This is most likely what happened.

Comment: This should be the correct answer to the issue reported.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this by adding the Table attribute on the EF table object, and then renaming the object to something like MyEntityMyProp.  I then refactored by code to use the new object name.  This was more simple than renaming the database table.

```
[Table("MyEntity_MyProp")]
public class MyEntityMyProp
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check `ApplicationDbContext` in your project.

maybe your entity name used as the property name in `public DbSet<>`.