# How to fix 'Ambiguous match found' while using linq and entity framework core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

**SOLUTION**: *After switching to .Net Core 2.2 it worked perfectly*. There is some issue with .Net Core 3.0.100-preview4-010549 and EFC.

While executing linq queries i keep geting error Ambiguous match found. I fear that solution might be really simple but i can't see it.

I googled it and so far didn't found solution. Only info i found is that EE throws "Ambiguous match found." when it finds hidden properties but as far i understood it is only when there are derived classes in project - which i don't have.

I am using Northwind database from this script:
https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/databases/northwind-pubs

I have found this thread but didn't help much [Entity Framework Exception: Ambiguous match found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245686/entity-framework-exception-ambiguous-match-found/18246694)
But maybe i don't see something?

I get error while executing this, really simple query.

```cs
var query = from customer in context.Customers select customer;

foreach (var item in query) // error occurs when first item is going to be initialized
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.ContactName}");
}

// Class genereted using  Scaffold-DbContext 
public partial class Customers
{
    public Customers()
    {
        CustomerCustomerDemo = new HashSet<CustomerCustomerDemo>();
        Orders = new HashSet<Orders>();
    }

    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string ContactTitle { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CustomerCustomerDemo> CustomerCustomerDemo { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Orders> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

The stack trace and error message:
https://gist.github.com/dealen/0fc207295c71b2bda3f47dbeafac58a5

Message "Ambiguous match found."

Version of Entity framework Core is: 2.2.4

Version of .Net Core: 3.0.100-preview4-010549

Comment: What does `Customers` inherit from? Perhaps in another class.

Comment: What does your context look like? There might also be an issue with the data

Comment: @Shahzad 
My context is here:https://gist.github.com/dealen/8c18e9b3c62f870deb0f190a0b3ef9d9
Databse is from script but maybe the data is an issue.
https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/databases/northwind-pubs

Comment: @mjwills there is keyword partial but i dont have second implementation of this class in project . Anyway, i have deleted all partial words and it is still the same.

Comment: Does something else inherit from `Customers`?

Comment: Does the problem occur if you use .NET Core 2.x?

Comment: @mjwills I have just tried it and no, after switching to .Net Core 2.2 it's all good.

Comment: @mjwills Thank you for help, shouldn't rush so much with preview.

Comment: Have a great day! Perhaps write the answer as an answer below, to help the next person who runs into the issue.